# Proving a set is a vector space, proving a norm, and that the set with the norm is a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $c$ be the space of sequences of real numbers that converge. That is $x\in c$ means that $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$ and $lim_{j\to \infty} x_j$ exists. It is easy to verify that $c$ is a vector space. For $x\in c$ define $\|x\|=sup_{j\in \mathbb{N}}|x_j|$. Verify that this is a norm that that $c$ with this norm is a Banach space.

So this is what I am thinking... was hoping to get any input on it. Thanks!

**Proving $c$ is a vector space**

Let $x,y\in c$, then $(x+y)=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,...)=(x_1,x_2,...)+(y_1,y_2,...)=(x)+(y)$ so $(x+y)\in c$.

Let $x\in c$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$, then $(ax)=(ax_1,ax_2,...)=a(x_1,x_2,...)=a(x)$ so $a(x)\in c$.

Let $x,0\in c$ such that $0=(0,0,0,...)$. Then $(x+0)=(x_1+0,x_2+0,...)=(x_1,x_2,...)+(0,0,...)=(x_1,x_2,...)+0=(x)+0=(x)$

Finally let $x,y\in c$ such that $y=-x=(-x_1,-x_2,...)$ so then $(x+y)=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,...)=(x_1-x_1,x_2-x_2,...)=(0,0,...)$ so $y$ is the additive inverse of $x$ and $y\in c$.

**Prove $\|x\|$ is a norm**

Let $x=0$ then $\|x\|=\|0\|=sup|0|=0$. Now assume $\|x\|=sup|x|=0$ then it is clear that $x=0$.

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in c$, then $\|ax\|=sup|ax|=sup|a||x|=|a|sup|x|=|a|\|x\|$

Let $x,y\in c$. Then $\|x+y\|=sup|x+y|\leq sup|x|+sup|y|=\|x\|+\|y\|$

**Proving $c$ with $\|x\|$ is a Banach space**

I am unsure how to show that a sequence of convergent sequences, converges... any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Everything is ok, unless your argument on completeness, which is a bit unclear. You should be more careful: what is a Cauchy sequence in $c$? Remember that it is a sequence of converging sequences...

Comment: For the last part you're not done. What you need to show is that a sequence *of sequences* in the $c$-norm converges if it is Cauchy!

Comment: So I am a bit unclear what you both mean... do you mean that I need to show that for $\{x_n\}\in c$ such that for $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N>0$ such that $\|x_n-x_m\|\leq \epsilon , n,m\geq N$, and therefore it is Cauchy? Not quite sure if that is the right idea...

Comment: Any input on my comment?

Comment: @Crostul any input on my comment above?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a bit confused by the notation.

Proving that $c$ is a Banach space:

Let $\{ x^n \}_n \subset c$ a Cauchy sequence. Every $x^n$ is a converging sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. We denote its elements by $\{ x^n_k \}_k$.

This means that

$$x^1 = x^1_1, x^1_2, x^1_3, x^1_4, x^1_5, \dots $$
$$x^2 = x^2_1, x^2_2, x^2_3, x^2_4, x^2_5, \dots $$
$$x^3 = x^3_1, x^3_2, x^3_3, x^3_4, x^3_5, \dots $$
and so on.

Being a Cauchy sequence means that

$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \, \, \exists N \geq 1 | \, \, \forall n,m \geq N 
\, \, \, \, \sup_{k \geq 1}|x^n_k - x^m_k| < \varepsilon
$$

We want to show that it is convergent to some $X \in c$. Now, elements of $c$ are converging sequences, hence we have to define the sequence $X= \{ X_k \}_k$.

The most natural way to define it is the following:
$$X_k = \lim_{n\to + \infty} x^n_k$$

And now, you should prove the three following facts to conclude:

1. For all $k\geq 1$ the limit defining $X_k$ exists and is finite
2. $X \in c$, i.e. $\lim_{k\to + \infty} X_k$ exists and is finite
3. $x_^n$ converges to $X$ in $c$, i.e.

$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \, \, \exists N \geq 1 | \, \, \forall n \geq N 
\, \, \, \, \sup_{k \geq 1}|x^n_k - X_k| < \varepsilon$$