# How to know if a space has a convergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

So this is something I have been struggling with lately... how do we generally know that a space/set has a subsequence that converges?

The current one I am struggling with is the space of sequences of real numbers that converge...

I have seen proofs of convergence (or proving something is Cauchy) usually start with something along the lines of "Let $\{x_n\} \in S$ be a convergent subsequence"... but how do we actually know if a set has one?

Thanks for helping out with this!

Comment: If you have a bounded sequence $\{ s_{n}\}$ of numbers, you can always extract a convergent subsequence. Or, if you have a bounded subsequence, then you can extract a subsequence of the bounded subsequence which converges, which is then a convergent subsequence of the original sequence. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Well with my example above, the space is composed of sequences of real numbers that converge... how could I show that this space has convergent subsequences (or more specifically, that the space is Cauchy)?

Comment: Are you, by any chance, dealing with equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences that define real numbers?

Comment: May you should a new question: about the completeness of the space of converging sequences... As such the question's wording is to imprecise.

Comment: see eg http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191110/how-to-prove-that-this-metric-space-is-complete

Comment: It actually has to do with the last section of this other problem I posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936159/proving-a-set-is-a-vector-space-proving-a-norm-and-that-the-set-with-the-norm  (the part about showing $c$ with $\|x\|$ is a Banach space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compactness of $S$ is the key.

Comment: So any idea with my example? The space of sequences of real numbers that converge, and showing that the space itself is Cauchy?

Comment: It depends on the norm you choose, after all it is an infinite-dimensional space. Usually this space is denoted by $c$.

Answer (score 0):

In any non-empty space, X, the sequence $a_n= a$, where a is any member of X, trivially converges to a.